# Regex to match absence of substring

Tags: regex, perl

I am looking for a regex which only matches when certain sub-strings are not present. In particular - if a line of code does not assign or return the return value from a method.

Examples:

```
this.execute(); // should match

var x = this.execute(); // no match

return this.execute(); // no match
```

I was trying to use the following regex

```
^(?!.*=|return).*execute\(\).*
```

This works with regex testers etc. - but I am getting "invalid perl operator" exception when using in practice.

Thanks..

Comment: 1) `^(?!.*=|return).*execute\(\).*` works perfectly fine in Perl 5.8+. 2) `invalid perl operator` is not an error issued by Perl (and if it was, it doesn't sound like an error the regex engine would throw). Please provide the actual code you ran.

Comment: Tip: The trailing `.*` is useless.

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to exclude only assignment or return it's easily negated

```
while (<DATA>) { print if not /(?:=|return)\s+this\.execute/ }

__DATA__
this.execute();
var x = this.execute();
return this.execute();
```

This prints only the line `this.execute();`.

---

With [Lookaround Assertions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Lookaround-Assertions), a *negative lookahead* that you offer does work

```
if (/^(?!.*=|return)\s+this\.execute/x) { print "$_\n" }
```

As for the *negative lookbehind*, there is one problem. First, here's what works

```
if ( /(?<! =\s )       this\.execute/x ) { print "$_\n" }
if ( /(?<! return \s ) this\.execute/x ) { print "$_\n" }
```

This excludes `=` *or* `return`, with *one space*. The thing is, we can't put `\s+` there nor can we do alternation -- Perl can't do it for this particular assertion, see [perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind). We get

```
Variable length lookbehind not implemented in regex m/(?<!=\s+)this\.execute/ at
```

We can add varying space `\s+` outside of the assertion, with `this...`, and then combine multiple conditions to provide for a possibility that there is no space between `=` and `this...`.

However, there's no reason for this if you can use a regular negated match.

---

The reported error can only be about basic syntax. It is about the exact code you run, not the regex.

Answer (score 1):

Not so sure if I understand the question but you might consider trying this one. `^this.execute\(\);`

Answer (score 1):

With situations like these, its best to find the "lowest common denominator" in the matches you want to distinguish from similar looking strings.  In this case, the `var x` can be ignored - your requirements are satisfied by saying "anything before the method call is ok - the method call alone is not."  That statement is probably a bit too tight though, so let's change it to "anthing other than whitespace before the method call is ok, otherwise flag the call".  Which means;

```
my $method_call = qr/ ( this \. \w+ ) \( /x;
while (<$fh>) {
    if (/ ^ \s* $method_call /x) {
        warn "Found method call on line $.: $1\n"
    }
}
```

I'm presumming `$fh` is a filehandle to the souce code file.  I've also made some presumptions which you may need to tweek about how you want to define a method call - ie. opening bracket for parameters is compulsory.  Using 'extended mode regexs' allows the use of whitespace in the regex for easier reading.  Also, using 'quote rule' allows referring to a regex by name inside another to make things clearer.

If on the other hand, you want to insist on the presence of `var x` or `return` before giving the ok, we can reverse the search - ie explicitly look for the "ok" situations and flag any other calls:

```
my $method_call = qr/ ( this \. \w+ ) \( /x;
while (<$fh>) { 
    next if / ^ \s* return \s+ $method_call /x;         # return OK
    next if / ^ \s* var \s+ \w+ = \s+ $method_call /x;  # var OK

    warn "Found method call on line $.: $1\n" if /$method_call/ ;
}
```

Both of these are a little verbose but show more clearly what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think we have enough information here. I say this because the following works for me in the shell

```
~$ echo "execute()"| perl -ne 'print if /^(?!.*=|return).*execute\(\).*/'
execute()
~$ echo "return execute()"| perl -ne 'print if /^(?!.*=|return).*execute\(\).*/'

~$
```

In the above code, I am running a one liner in a shell that pipes a string into a perl program. The perl program will print the string if it matches the regex. I get no errors from your regex.

It's possible that the error is due to your version of perl or something else entirely may be happening.

I am using perl v5.22.2

Comment: Does the prompt really show on your output lines? How confusing!

Comment: lawl, no it doesn't. I wasn't sure how to show that there is no output on the second command, so I added the ~$

Comment: Add a trailing `~$`, or `print // ? "match\n" : "no match\n"` or `print // ? "$_ matches\n" : "$_ doesn't match\n"`

Comment: ah! good call. i've never actually written perl before now ;]

Answer (score 0):

I mean, the *simple* answer is, just use the `!` operator on your test, but here's the conversion in case you were wondering:
`/expression/` => `/^(?!.*expression)/` (either use DOTALL or `[^]` in JavaScript)
`/^expression/` => `/^(?!expression)/`